# Is it possible for mount(8) to override systemd MountFlags?

Tags: debian, mount, systemd, namespace

I am working on `Debian stretch/4.14.75` and have been
using my own automounter (`udev-hook + shell-script`)
for years.

Since it breaks recently due to the namespace problem
that the mounted directory is not visible elsewhere except
that terminal opened by the `automounter-script`.

Although

```
# sed -i "/^MountFlags/s/=.*$/=shared/" \
    /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
```

made it good again, I wonder if it is possible for
`mount(8)` or some other manipupation to do a 
one-shot-propagation of the namespace back to the
`root`(?) namespace.

I think they must have a good reason making `MountFlags=slave` the default, or?

Comment: Possibly related: [\[systemd-devel\] Why did you set MountFlags=slave in systemd-udevd.service.in](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2018-February/040412.html)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't really propagate mounts back to the root namespace once you're running on a detached mount namespace.

Other than disabling the mount namespace sandboxing, you can use [`systemd-mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-mount.html) to fix the issue.

#### Rationale for sandboxing

systemd prefers to have udev rules not mount filesystems directly, but rather tell it to start units (such as mount units) from udev rules. That's why udevd runs in a separate mount namespace (with `MountFlags=slave`), to prevent mistakes in rules or rules that want to temporarily mount a filesystem to pollute the host mounts.

But, of course, in your case, that's what you want to do, through your automounter script.

#### systemd-mount

You can adapt your automounter script to work within the separate mount namespace of udevd, by simply replacing the calls to `mount` with [`systemd-mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-mount.html), which is a tool that takes the same arguments as `mount` (as far as possible) but that mounts the filesystems by asking systemd to do so (more specifically, by creating a [mount unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) and an [automount unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) for it, both units created under the transient `/run/systemd/system` directory which is not preserved on reboot.)

#### Disabling mount sandbox with an override

If you really want to disable the sandboxing of mount namespaces of udevd, then use an override configuration file to do so, rather than modifying the one shipped in `/lib` with the systemd package (which will probably get clobbered next time the package is upgraded by apt.)

You can open an override file in your editor with:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-udevd
```

Where you can reset `MountFlags` to its default ("shared") with the following two lines:

```
[Service]
MountFlags=
```

Setting a variable to an empty string usually resets it to its default in systemd.

Please note that in recent versions of systemd this is now configured using `PrivateMounts=` instead, for instance, see the [commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/b2e8ae7380d009ab9f9260a34e251ac5990b01ca) that converts the udevd service file to use it.

Which highlights one of the problems with the override: you're deviating from standard systemd configuration, so you might end up having to adapt from time to time as you need additional or alternative configuration to keep this working as you upgrade to newer systemd.

Also, you lose the benefits of sandboxing udevd to its own mount namespace in first place.

So, if the solution using `systemd-mount` works for you, I'd recommend it over the override.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem by simply replacing mount(8) with systemd-mount(1). But I sort of wonder why they are putting systemd-mount to (1) while mount in (8).

Answer (score 1):

systemd units are stored in these locations:

```
   /etc/systemd/system/* - local configuration
   /run/systemd/system/* - runtime units
   /usr/lib/systemd/system/* - units of installed packages
```

When you want to modify something, you shouldn't modify file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` directory, but you should create new unit file with the same name in `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.

From `man systemd.unit`:

> There are two methods of overriding vendor settings in unit files: copying the unit file from */usr/lib/systemd/system* to */etc/systemd/system* and modifying the chosen settings. Alternatively, one can create a directory named *unit.d/* within */etc/systemd/system* and place a drop-in file *name.conf* there that only changes the specific settings one is interested in. Note that multiple such drop-in files are read if present.
>
> The advantage of the first method is that one easily overrides the complete unit, the vendor unit is not parsed at all anymore. It has the disadvantage that improvements to the unit file by the vendor are not automatically incorporated on updates.
>
> The advantage of the second method is that one only overrides the settings one specifically wants, where updates to the unit by the vendor automatically apply. This has the disadvantage that some future updates by the vendor might be incompatible with the local changes.

`systemd` has its own mechanism for mounting volumes as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Mounting):

> systemd is in charge of mounting the partitions and filesystems specified in /etc/fstab. The systemd-fstab-generator(8) translates all the entries in /etc/fstab into systemd units, this is performed at boot time and whenever the configuration of the system manager is reloaded.

I think using your own automounter with systemd will give you more problems than it's necessary.