# udev rule works with command echo but not with cp command

Tags: scripting, udev

I wrote a udev rule for automatic copy files from my USB key to my computer.

```
ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="sd[d-z][1-9]",ATTRS{serial}=="0701278A8DAE6B42",RUN+="/home/marco/Documents/MesScripts/essai_udev.sh"
```

My script is :

```
#!/bin/sh 
exec /bin/cp /media/marco/EMTEC/2nde_2023_2024/DS1/DS1.pdf /home/marco/Documents/Travail/Malherbe/2nde/Malherbe_2023_2024/DS/DS1/
```

where EMTEC is my USB key. I've also tried to write only "cp" or "/bin/cp" but nothing work. If I change this command by

```
echo "Hello!" > toto.txt *
```

it works !
Somebody could help me please ?

Comment: My guess: udev detected a block device was added. However there's no mounted filesystem... yet.

Comment: so do I need to add the mount command in my script or in my udev rule ? if so, how can I do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure about what to do, that's why this was just a comment. Maybe this should not be done from udev but from elsewhere, perhaps a systemd component that depends on the mount (since something will do this mount automatically in the next seconds, won't it?). You'll have to check these ideas or wait for somebody else's answer.

Comment: When I connect my USB key, my Debian recognize it and I can navigate in it with the terminal and so on. I can execute my script in command line and it works, but not with the udev rule ...

Comment: that's why I wrote "in the next seconds". steps 1/ block device D appears, 2/ then filesystem F present inside D gets mounted. Your script runs between steps 1 and 2. It should run after step 2. Again I tell what happens, not how to solve it (because I don't know).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try different things but I don't know how to do that :-(

Answer (score 0):

`udev` is for simple tasks that set a device for later use (by other parts of the system), not tasks that actually use a device. Such complex tasks are preferably done by external applications that listen on udev events, like [udisksd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/udisksd.8.html) (mounts), [NetworkManager](https://linux.die.net/man/8/networkmanager) (networking), etc.

From the [udev manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udev.7.html):

> `RUN{type}` (...) can only be used for very short-running foreground
> tasks. Running an event process for a long period of time may
> block all further events for this or a dependent device.
>
> **Note that running programs that** access the network or
> **mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev
> rules**, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on
> systemd-udevd.service.
>
> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not
> allowed; the forked processes, detached or not, will be
> unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.
> In order to activate long-running processes from udev rules,
> provide a service unit and pull it in from a udev device
> using the SYSTEMD_WANTS device property. See
> [systemd.device(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.device.5.html) for details.

What I emphasized means that the file system is never mounted when your rule is executed, that's why your `cp` command fails.

If you plan to bypass your system's automount and mount your device yourself, see [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476332/203203).

I personally would let my system automount the device as usual, and listen to some event in order to trigger the `cp` operation. Depending on your system and on your taste, that might be a [D-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) event, or use [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to catch FS events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to add mount command in my script .sh et execute this script in my udev rules by adding a sudo to force it to be executed by my user and not root.